# Modify the title of the shiny application in golem in the tab of the web browser

Tags: shiny, golem

I am developing a shiny application using `golem` as framework. I noticed that when I run the application, the browser page tab shows the name of the package defined in '`01_start.R`' (e.g. pkg_name = "*golem.test*").

I have tried to include this code in the ui but it doesn't work:

```
app_ui <- function(request) {
  # ...
  tags$head(tags$title("My New Title"))
  # ...
}
```

But it doesn't work. It still shows "golem.test".

How and where can I change the title of the application so that it is displayed correctly in the tab?.

Thank you very much.
Wardiam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the app_ui file, there should be a golem_add_external_resource function. It is in this function that we can change the name of the application tab, the favicon etc...

Your app_ui may look like this :

```r
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    #Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources()
  )
}

golem_add_external_resources <- function(){
  tags$head(
    bundle_resources(
    #Change the title of the application here
      app_title = "My new Title"
    )
  )
}
```